# unresolved external symbol, but dumpbin says it's ok

Tags: c++, unresolved-external, crypto++

I downloaded `Crypto++` 5.62 and built it with default project settings. In my project I set up the path to `cryptopp.lib` and defined its name in "Additional Dependencies". Both Crypto++ and my project - VS 2008.

During building of my project I get:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
  "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL" (?DEFAULT_CHANNEL@CryptoPP@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@B)

main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
  "bool (__cdecl* CryptoPP::g_pAssignIntToInteger)(class type_info const &,void *,void const *)" (?g_pAssignIntToInteger@CryptoPP@@3P6A_NABVtype_info@@PAXPBX@ZA)
```

`dumpbin /all cryptopp.lib` shows me in the public symbols section

```
19471C _imp_?DEFAULT_CHANNEL@CryptoPP@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@B

1D6F30 __imp_?g_pAssignIntToInteger@CryptoPP@@3P6A_NABVtype_info@@PAXPBX@ZA
```

What's wrong then? Why the linker can't find the symbols?

**upd:**

linker command line from my project settings

`/OUT:"C:\Projects\crypto_hash\Debug\crypto_hash.exe" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"e:\libs\cryptopp\cryptopp562\cryptopp\Win32\DLL_Output\Debug" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\crypto_hash.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Projects\crypto_hash\Debug\crypto_hash.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT cryptopp.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib`

Comment: missing dependency? messed up include?

Comment: @staticx: i'm not sure i understand you. Could you please explain more detaily?

Comment: can you look at your output window and see what link.exe command is used?

Comment: do you have two projects in your solution? where is your main.cpp file? Is it a project that depends on cryptopp.lib?

Comment: @evpo: the projects are separated, each one is placed in its onw solution. My project uses cryptopp.lib

Comment: the linker command you posted is from cryptopp.dll but the errors are from the calling project, right? Can I see the link.exe command from the project where your main.cpp is?

Comment: @evpo: that linker command line i posted is from my own project which uses cryptopp.dll (main.cpp is in this project), not from project which builds cryptopp.dll.

Comment: Then how do you explain that the output of that project is "OUT:"Win32\DLL_Output\Debug\cryptopp.dll"?

Comment: @evpo: I'm sorry, it's my mistake. I've update to the right command line.

Comment: That's alright. The linker command looks ok to me. Try to make sure that your compilation switches match between cryptopp.dll and crypto_hash.exe. Things like /MTd and so on.

Comment: @evpo: if i build ``cryptopp`` as ``lib``, not ``dll`` with ``/MDd`` (like in my own project), it works. But it doesn't in the case of ``dll``. Anyway, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS` to your project defines.

From `config.h`:

```
#ifdef CRYPTOPP_EXPORTS
# define CRYPTOPP_IS_DLL
# define CRYPTOPP_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined(CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS)
# define CRYPTOPP_IS_DLL
# define CRYPTOPP_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#else
# define CRYPTOPP_DLL
#endif
```

Or include Crypto++'s `dll.h`. It sets `CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS`:

```
#if !defined(CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS) && !defined(CRYPTOPP_EXPORTS) && !defined(CRYPTOPP_DEFAULT_NO_DLL)
# ifdef CRYPTOPP_CONFIG_H
#  error To use the DLL version of Crypto++, this file must be included before any other Crypto++ header files.
# endif
# define CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS
#endif
```

---

If that does not work...

`g_pAssignIntToInteger` is from `algparams.cpp`:

```
$ grep -R g_pAssignIntToInteger *
algparam.cpp:PAssignIntToInteger g_pAssignIntToInteger = NULL;
algparam.h:CRYPTOPP_DLL extern PAssignIntToInteger g_pAssignIntToInteger;
algparam.h:     if (!(g_pAssignIntToInteger != NULL && typeid(T) == typeid(int) && g_pAssignIntToInteger(valueType, pValue, &m_value)))
integer.cpp:    if (!g_pAssignIntToInteger)
integer.cpp:        g_pAssignIntToInteger = AssignIntToInteger;
```

Looking at the declaration in `algparam.h`:

```
// to allow the linker to discard Integer code if not needed.
typedef bool (CRYPTOPP_API * PAssignIntToInteger)(const std::type_info &valueType, void *pInteger, const void *pInt);
CRYPTOPP_DLL extern PAssignIntToInteger g_pAssignIntToInteger;
```

And the implementation in `algparam.cpp`:

```
#ifndef CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS
...

NAMESPACE_BEGIN(CryptoPP)    
PAssignIntToInteger g_pAssignIntToInteger = NULL;
...
```

So you might need to change the implementation to ensure the code uses `g_pAssignIntToInteger` (to keep it from being discarded). Unfortunately, nothing comes to mind at the moment.

---

`DEFAULT_CHANNEL` is declared in `cryptlib.h` and has storage allocated in `cryptolib.cpp`:

```
$ grep -R DEFAULT_CHANNEL *
...
cryptlib.cpp:const std::string DEFAULT_CHANNEL;
...
cryptlib.h:extern CRYPTOPP_DLL const std::string DEFAULT_CHANNEL;
...
```

This might be a different problem since I'm not used to seeing issues with `DEFAULT_CHANNEL`. See how `CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS` works for you, and then ask a different question since this might be a different problem.

Comment: #include <dll.h> before all other crypto-includes solved the problem for me too.