# LNK1104 Cryptopp.lib with CRYPTOPP_DEFAULT_NO_DLL defined in dll project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, crypto++

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, with the 2012 toolset and I'm trying to split an win32 executable project up into an exe that consumes a dll that contains all the program logic. The end goal is to be able to create a seperate project for unit tests that can link against the new dll.

Now the old version of the project compiles absolutely fine and uses cryptlib.lib (thanks SVN!), but once I separated it out in to a dll with the program logic and the same project settings I get the following error when I attempt to build the dll:

Error   546 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cryptopp.lib'

I have the directory that contains cryptlib.lib in my linker settings and I'm linking against it just as I did in the previous project settings. Based on the documentation it shouldn't be trying to link against cryptopp.lib because CRYPTOPP_DEFAULT_NO_DLL is defined in the preprocessor settings.

I also tried adding the directory that contains cryptopp.lib to the VC++ directory paths and I added cryptopp.lib to my linker settings, and it still gives me the same error. I don't want to use the dll version of cryptopp, but at this point I just need the thing to work.

All the projects are using the 2012 toolsets, and all are being compiled as win32 projects so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hmm, mixing up "cryptlib.lib" and "cryptopp.lib" is the kind of mistake you'll make when you've working for 10+ hours.  Go home, pop a beer, kiss the girl, you'll sort it out tomorrow in ten minutes.

Comment: Maybe, I've been screwing around with it for over a day now. But I think you are correct, it's some stupid thing that will have me slapping my head at some point.

Comment: *"... once I separated it out in to a dll with the program logic and the same project settings ..."* - I'm not clear what you are doing in this step. The Crypto++ DLL is intended for FIPS Validation. It does not build a general purpose DLL for Windows. When you want a DLL for Windows, you should provide the DLL wrapper and link to `cryptlib`.

Comment: I'm sorry my question wasn't worded very well.

I'm splitting up a project that uses cryptopp, I'm not trying to make changes to the cryptopp library itself.

Comment: *"'m using Visual Studio 2013, with the 2012 toolset ..."* - Oh my, this is an entire can of worms. MSBuild changed a lot in 2010, and most of it was ***not*** for the better as far as Crypto++ is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out what was happening, if not why. For some reason the preprocessor definitions don't seem to be getting applied. If I put CRYPTOPP_DEFAULT_NO_DLL at the top of all the include files it works as expected.

Comment: You should probably read the comments in [dll.h](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/dll_8h_source.html). I think what you are looking for is `CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS`. Crypto++'s `dlltest` project sets it in the project's preprocessor macros. Also see [unresolved external symbol, but dumpbin says it's ok](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22686709).

Comment: I wound up delete the project file and creating a new one. All the same settings, but now it works. I'm just moving on at this point and chalking it up to visual studio doing strange things.

I'm going to watch out for more instances of it, to try and understand what caused it.